# Where can I find data of NFL players and clubs?

Tags: american-football, nfl, statistics

I am going to take Spanish soccer league players and clubs data from a business API.

The purpose is to generate a quiz app with questions as "Which player has scored more goals this season?" and try to earn a bit with advertisements and subscriptions.

I wonder if I could do the same for NFL if it is not very expensive to take the data.

Comment: Not 100% sure if its what you're looking for - or indeed the pricing (there is a 90(?) day free trial - but you could take a look at [Sport Radar's NFL API](https://developer.sportradar.com/docs/read/american_football/NFL_v7) - specifically the [Player Profile endpoint](https://developer.sportradar.com/docs/read/american_football/NFL_v7#player-profile)

Comment: @ImClarky I see thank you. It looks an extensive API and what I need. I am gonna start to pay in September when the season starts to beSoccer 100€/month for the spanish soccer league data. I will contact Sport Radar to see if my budget covers it and I can publish in 2023 for the NFL too.

Comment: @IMClarky I come from having a videoconference with a Sport Radar employer and you need to have a company to buy their data. No possible for me, I am a small developper.